# Certificate Revocation of Java Application

Tags: java, glassfish, certificate, certificate-revocation

I have a Glassfish application which is using SSL Certificate authorized by private CA. When I launched a Glassfish application in client within intranet (without internet connection), it will prompt me errors (See Image1). Both errors show that they are unable to verify if the certificate is revoked.

[image: Image1:Errors]

However, when I disable the certificate revocation checks (See Image2), it does not prompt me any errors anymore.

[image: Image2:Java Control Panel]

If I don't do the step above, is there any way to disable the certificate revocation check by changing Glassfish configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Use `-Dcom.sun.net.ssl.checkRevocation=false` system property in your program